# Asymptotic behaviour of $\sum_{p\leq x} \frac{1}{p^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

As the title suggests, I want to find the asymptotic behaviour of this sum as $x\rightarrow \infty$, I tried by summation by parts but didn't succeed I also tried using the asymptotic behvaiour of the sum

$$\sum_{p\leq x} \frac{1}{p} \sim_{x \to \infty} \log \log x$$

i.e squaring both sides gives me:

$$\sum_{p\leq x} \frac{1}{p^2} + \sum_{\substack{q,p\leq x\\p\neq q}} \frac{1}{pq} \sim_{x \to \infty} \log^2(\log x)$$

But then, how do I estimate the second term in the LHS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The sum is bounded, so asymptotically it is constant.

Comment: @AlexBecker: I took the approach of looking at the asymptotic behavior of the tail; that is, the difference between the partial sum and the limit.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99007/rate-of-convergence-of-series-of-squared-prime-reciprocals

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The prime zeta function $P(s)$, for $\text{Real}(s) > 1$, is defined as
$$P(s) = \sum_{\overset{p=1}{p \text{ is prime}}}^{\infty} \dfrac1{p^s}$$
The sum converges for $\text{Real}(s) > 1$, similar to the $\zeta$-function. Your sum is $P(2)$ and is approximately $0.4522474200410654985065\ldots$.

There are no "nice" values for $P(s)$ where $s \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \backslash \{1\}$. A very crude argument why there are no "nice" values for $P(s)$ is due to the fact that the function, $$g(n) = \dfrac{\mathbb{I}_{n \text{ is a prime}}}{n^s}$$ is not a "nice" arithmetic function in the usual sense i.e. it is not even multiplicative for instance.

Comment: This function should have an asymptotic behaviour of $c \log^2\log x$, cause I have been asked to calculate the 4-th moment of the function $R_X(t)=\sum_{p\leq x} \frac{\sin(t\log p)}{\sqrt{p}}$, and to show that it's asymptotically behaves, for $x\in [T^{\delta},T^{1/2-\delta}]$ where $\delta \in (0,1/4)$ , like $c \log^2\log T$ for $T\rightarrow \infty$. In my calculations I ma led to find the sum $\sum_{p\leq x} \frac{1}{p^2}$ asymptotically. any tips as to how to solve this problem?!

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist I don't understand your comment. Your sum $\sum_{p = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p^2}$ converges. Hence, your sum  $\sum_{p \leq x} \frac{1}{p^2} = \mathcal{O}(1)$.

Comment: OK, thanks. sorry for the misunderstanding from my behalf.

Answer (score 12):

Using an estimate of the difference between the [prime counting function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function), $\pi(n)$ and the [logarithmic integral function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function), $\mathrm{li}(x)$, we can estimate the tail of the series.

Let $\Delta(n)=\pi(n)-\mathrm{li}(n)$. Without assuming the Riemann Hypothesis, we have that for any $m$
$$
\Delta(n)=O\left(\frac{\raise{2pt}n}{\log(n)^m}\right)\tag{1}
$$

Summing by parts and using $(1)$ with $m=2$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}(\Delta(k)-\Delta(k-1))
&=-\frac{\Delta(n-1)}{n^2}+\sum_{k=n}^\infty\Delta(k)\left(\frac{1}{k^2}-\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\right)\\
&=O\left(\frac{1}{n\log(n)^2}\right)\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Using $(2)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{p\ge n}\frac{1}{p^2}
&=\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}(\pi(k)-\pi(k-1))\\
&=\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}(\mathrm{li}(k)-\mathrm{li}(k-1))+O\left(\frac{1}{n\log(n)^2}\right)\\
&=\int_n^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2\log(x)}+O\left(\frac{1}{n\log(n)^2}\right)\\
&=\int_n^\infty\frac{\log(x)+1}{x^2\log(x)^2}\mathrm{d}x+O\left(\frac{1}{n\log(n)^2}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{n\log(n)}+O\left(\frac{1}{n\log(n)^2}\right)\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Do you have expertise in the stuff related to RH? If so, I would be interested if you can shoot down [this claimed proof](https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.5120), since there doesn't seem to be any published error (even though it should be easy since it's been so many years). If you ask me to bet, I would of course bet it is wrong, but I am just curious how bad the proof is haha. I myself know nothing about RH...

Comment: @user21820: I have very little expertise related to RH. I will take a look, but I doubt I will be able to find anything if no one else has in almost 8 years.

Comment: I see, thanks! I suspect it's just because it just happened to miss everyone's notice.