# Ask about the sequence of primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

I want to ask if there is this result $$\sum_{p\text{ are prime numbers}}\dfrac{1}{p^2}\approx 0.452224742...<\dfrac{1}{2}?$$
I sincerely thank you.

Comment: [Related](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53443/sum-of-the-reciprocal-of-the-primes-squared).

Comment: @Gae.S. Note the related MO post you provided is also linked to in the first question comment of my proposed duplicate Math SE question.

Comment: Note I found a likely better duplicate to use of [How to prove $\sum_p p^{-2} < \frac{1}{2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1552136/how-to-prove-sum-p-p-2-frac12).

Comment: Wow, great! I sincerely thank you very much. Good health!

Comment: Use that $$\sum_{p \ge k} p^{-2}\le\int_{k-1}^\infty x^{-2}dx= (k-1)^{-1}$$ taking $k=17$ gives your result.