# Example of divergent series whose associated "squared" series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I am trying to find a non-trivial example of a series with positive terms $a_n$ that satisfies the following two conditions:

$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} a_n = +\infty \qquad \text{and} \qquad \sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} a_n^2 < +\infty.
$$

The obvious example is of course $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$, but could you help me finding another one? Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: Slightly less trivial:  $a_n = 1/n^p$ for any $p \in (1/2,1]$

Comment: You might find the [divergence of prime reciprocals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15946/does-the-sum-of-reciprocals-of-primes-converge) interesting.  It supplies a "modern" proof of the infinitude of primes.  Convergence of the [squared prime reciprocals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99007/rate-of-convergence-of-series-of-squared-prime-reciprocals) is also previously discussed.

Comment: Another class of less trivial $n^{a+p}\sin(\frac{1}{n^{2p+a}})$ for $p\in(1/2,1]$ and any $a$.